# find an object with the latest timestamp string that is earlier than a reference value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapreduce

I have the following code to go through an array of objects and find the object with a timestamp that is still smaller of a reference value but the biggest of those

```
    for (const elem of objs) {
        if (elem._time >= failureTime) {//we are one too far
            break;          
        } else {
            temp = elem; //this will end up as the last element with timestamp before event
           }
        }
```

This assumes that objs is ordered by timestamp, which I can't predict so I need to reorder it every time. I tried to create a .reduce function to solve that but horribly failed. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I guess, you could collect all elements, which have a timestamp smaller (earlier) than the reference, in a new array and then find the element with the largest (latest) timestamp in that array.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking how to find the largest time less than `failureTime` when `objs` **isn't** sorted, you just don't stop when you see an out-of-range value. Instead, you ignore those, and keep track of the highest in-range value you've seen:

```
let temp = null;
for (const elem of objs) {
    if (elem._time < failureTime && (temp === null || elem._time > temp._time)) {
        temp = elem;
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const objs = [
    { _time: new Date("2022-01-02T00:00:00.000Z") },
    { _time: new Date("2022-01-04T00:00:00.000Z") },
    { _time: new Date("2022-01-03T00:00:00.000Z") },
    { _time: new Date("2022-01-06T00:00:00.000Z") },
    { _time: new Date("2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") },
];
const failureTime = new Date("2022-01-05T00:00:00.000Z");
let temp = null;
for (const elem of objs) {
    if (elem._time < failureTime && (temp === null || elem._time > temp._time)) {
        temp = elem;
    }
}
console.log(temp._time);
```

Comment: Thank you! sometimes you don't see the simple elegant solution when you have set your mind on  a fancy function... Your solution works great.

Comment: @peterandree - I know that feeling well. :-)

Comment: Looks like I need to sort the array first and then go with the original approach. The change added 5-10 secs to my execution time. Its in a loop but the arrays are really small (between 5 and max 2000 entries) That's quite surprising, but I blame the underlying infrastructure

Comment: @peterandree - That'll work if you **keep** the array sorted, but if you have to sort every time before finding the value above, that should take *longer*. In general, sorting an array takes longer than than a single loop through it.

Comment: unfortunately its not kept in  a sorted state. It actually regenerates every x minutes and than looped through 5 to 2000 times, much more often in the single digits than in the triple digits. Maybe 10 comparisons on average during the life cycle of the array. I guess I should make sure that I receive the arrays in a sorted state. Those 10 secs cost my customer some noticeable amount of money, which isn't nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reduce` method;

```
//failureTime
arr.reduce((acc,key)=>{
if(acc._time <= failureTime){
 if(acc._time < key._time) return key;
 else return acc;
} 
},arr[0]);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Two bugs in the above: 1. It will fail if any element doesn't match `acc._time <= failureTime` since the callback returns `undefined` in that case (a classic example of why `reduce` is overcomplicated and shouldn't be used outside of functional programming with predefined, tested, reusable reducer functions). 2. It will return the wrong result if `arr[0]` is `>= failureTime`, because you're taking `arr[0]` as the initial accumulator. (Also, the comparison should be `< failureTime`, not `<= failureTime`, given the OP's code. I'd also at least mention you renamed `objs` to `arr`.)

Comment: thanks, that looks interesting. Not sure it improves the readability though, but I will see how it works and take it as a learning experience

Comment: @peterandree - Beware of the `reduce` method. It was added for the functional programming crowd (which is fine) but then got picked up and dramatically overused outside its realm if you will. Using `reduce` with an inline reducer function is just coding an overcomplicated loop that's easily messed up (as Manoj did here). I ([and](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544) [others](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1213077702300852224)) strongly recommend not using it except with predefined, reusable, tested reducer functions. Just use a loop. :-)

Comment: Wow! I have read through your thread and I can totally see that I should tread very careful here. Loops look like a good and natural alternative, even though I tend to not immediately understand their function when KI review older code. that why I wanted to evaluate alternative. But not in my case here.